# Finding/Remapping bounds of OpenGL ES coordinate plane

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm trying to make 2D graphics for my Android app that consists of six thin rectangles that each take up about 1/6th of the screen in width and equal the screen's height. I'm not sure the right way to determine the bounds of the x and y OpenGL coordinate plane on screen. Eventually I will need to write logic that tests which of the 6 rectangles a touch event occurs in, so I have been trying to solve this problem by remapping OpenGL's coordinate plane into the device's screen coordinate plane (where the origin (0,0) is at the top left of the screen instead of the middle.

I declare one of my six rectangles like so:

```
private float vertices1[] = {
            2.0f,  10.0f, 0.0f,  // 0, Top Left
            2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
            4.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
            4.0f,  10.0f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right
    };
```

but since i'm not sure what the visible limits are on the x and y planes (in the OpenGL coordinate system) I have no concrete way of knowing what vertices my rectangle needs to be instantiated with to occupy 1/6th of the display. Whats the ideal way to do this?

I've tried approaches such as [using glOrthoof()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571402/explain-the-usage-of-glortho) to remap OpenGL's coordinates into easy to work with device screen coordinates:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
// Select the projection matrix
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
// Reset the projection matrix
gl.glLoadIdentity();
// Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,(float) width / (float) height,0.1f, 100.0f);
gl.glOrthof(0.0f,width,height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 5.0f);
// Select the modelview matrix
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
// Reset the modelview matrix
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

but when I do my rectangle dissapears completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly don't want to use a perspective projection for 2D graphics. That just doesn't make much sense. A perspective projection is for... well, creating a perspective projection, which is only useful if your objects are actually placed in 3D space.

Even worse, you have two calls to set up a perspective matrix:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,(float) width / (float) height,0.1f, 100.0f);
gl.glOrthof(0.0f,width,height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 5.0f);
```

While that's legal, it rarely makes sense. What essentially happens if you do this is that both projections are applied in succession. So the first thing to do is get rid of the `gluPerspective()` call.

To place your 6 rectangles, you have a few options. Almost the easiest one is to not apply any transformations at all. This means that you will specify your input coordinates in normalized device coordinates (aka NDC), which is a range of [-1.0, 1.0] in both the x- and y-direction. So for 6 rectangles rendered side by side, you would use a y-range of [-1.0, 1.0] for all the rectangles, and an x-range of [-1.0, -2.0/3.0] for the first, [-2.0/3.0, -1.0/3.0] for the second, etc.

Another option is that you use an orthographic projection that makes specifying the rectangles even more convenient. For example, a range of [0.0, 6.0] for x and [0.0, 1.0] for y would make it particularly easy:

```
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, 6.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Then all rectangles have a y-range of [0.0, 1.0], the first rectangle has a x-range of [0.0, 1.0], the second rectangle [1.0, 2.0], etc.

BTW, if you're just starting with OpenGL, I would pass on ES 1.x, and directly learn ES 2.0. ES 1.x is a legacy API at this point, and I wouldn't use it for any new development.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm currently switching over to GLES 2.0; will the two solutions you outlined work the same for GLES 2.0?