# moving camera using glOrtho

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having a problem with moving my camera with glOrtho. I have a small quad in the center and i want to try to move the camera using glOrtho, but it just doesn't seem to be working. The quad doesn't move at all, so the camera isn't moving too i guess. maybe i miss understand how glOrtho works?
here is my code so far.

```
void Camera::updateCamera(float x, float y, float zoom)
{
    camX = x;
    camY = y;
    this->zoom = zoom;
    viewWidth = 320;
    viewHeight = 240;
    //viewWidth = tan(60) * this->zoom;
    //viewHeight = tan(45) * this->zoom;    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(camX - viewWidth,
        camX + viewWidth,
        camY - viewHeight,
        camY + viewHeight,
        -1,
        1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

and here is where i apply it. i tried to move it along the x axis for 25 points.

```
void Engine::renderAll()
{
    x += 25;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shader->use();
    camera.updateCamera(x, y, 1.0);
    //shader->setUniform4fv("view", camera.getView());
    batchManager->renderBatches();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

Comment: Is your shader actually using the projection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess you misundertood how glOrtho works. The role of glOrtho is transform a 3D view in a 2D view, using an orthographic projection.

If you want to work with positioning camera in a 3D space, the correct function is normally called LookAt. Once, it seems me that you are using old OpenGL, you can try the glu function [gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)

PS. In moderm openGL, this functions is now deprecated. I suggest you to try to learn the modern way.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention, i'm working in 2D, that's why i tried to use the glOrtho.

Comment: Not a problema. OpenGL is a 3D library/framework. Just keep one dimension constant

Comment: so, i can't use glOrtho for my camera?

Comment: If you want to do an orthographic projection, you not can, you must use it. But remember, camera has 2 roles: projection and positioning. Projection is done with glOrtho, for example, and position is done via vertex transformation, or in old OpenGL, gluLookAt

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571402/explain-the-usage-of-glortho?rq=1 for a better undestand about projection